# Webpack + TypeScript + Module Loading

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

Basically, module loading is a pain in JavaScript right now *sigh*...

So I have a TypeScript application I'd like to be compiled with webpack. The issue is that my editor (vscode) seems to expect that modules are imported *without* extensions. For example:

```
import {IServer} from "../server/server";
```

In webpack, I can only get this to work if I include an extension. If I include an extension (i.e. "../server/server.ts") it builds in webpack, but the editor doesn't recognize it and throws an error that the module wasn't found. If I omit an extension (i.e. "../server/server"), webpack *won't* load it (it says it can't find the module "../server/server"), but the editor will load it for purposes of code-completion, etc.

This leads me to believe that importing modules in TypeScript are expected to be done without extensions, whereas in the webpack ecosystem, they are required (which makes sense with how loaders work, etc).

This leaves a very bad taste in my mouth. My question here is: is my conclusion correct? Do I have to trade off between the build system or the editor? Or am I missing something? Is it possible to have the webpack typescript loader silently add in the extensions so the modules are properly recognized by webpack during the build?

I have the following webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        name: "Server",
        entry: "./src/server/server.ts",
        output: {
            filename: "./server/server.js"
        },
        target: "node",
        resolve: [".ts", ".js"],
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        name: "Client",
        entry: "./src/client/scripts/client.ts",
        output: {
            filename: "./public/scripts/client.js"
        },
        resolve: ["", ".ts", ".js", ".less"],
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
                { test: /\.less$/, loader: "style!css!less" },
                { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
                { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
                { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png" }
            ]
        }
    }
];
```

And the following tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "react"
    },

    "files": [
        "src/shared/typings/tsd.d.ts",
        "src/shared/typings/webpack.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

And I'm using the following packages in node:

```
"babel-core": "^6.2.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
"css-loader": "^0.23.0",
"file-loader": "^0.8.5",
"less": "^2.5.3",
"less-loader": "^2.2.1",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
"style-loader": "^0.13.0",
"ts-loader": "^0.7.1",
"typescript": "^1.6.2",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1",
"moment": "^2.10.6"
```

Comment: I realize that this is probably not really helpful, but SystemJS handles this very gracefully. I've had a great experience so far and it supports most Webpack features I am aware of.

Comment: I'm going though all of the mainstream module loading/build systems to decide for myself which ones that I prefer. SystemJS (via JSPM) is pretty nice, but I am not impressed with the performance of it without HTTP2. I have a large TS app that I'm porting between all of them, and I had terrible perf when loading all modules at runtime. Webpack seems to be *much* faster; but this issue is stumping me. Modules without extensions worked fine on RequireJS, JSPM and browserify, can't there be a way to do this with webpack without re-writing all of my imports?

Comment: I'm curious roughly how many files/modules are in your app. I've found the performance to be decent, but my app is only a few hundred files ts files, each about 20 to 40 loc.

Comment: That's odd. I was getting perf issues with just react being loaded. Even when I inject react/lodash/all other vendor libs, it still takes about half a second to a second to just load the core runtime modules. The amount of requests it makes is insane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is my conclusion correct

No. Extensions should definitely not be there.

## Fix

`resolve: [".ts", ".js"],`

Should be :

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
},
```

When in doubt, check the tests : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/tree/master/test

Answer (score 1):

> in webpack, I can only get this to work if I include an extension.

Definitely not needed.

> whereas in the webpack ecosystem, they are required

No again. They are not required.

> entry: "./src/server/server.ts",

This should be `entry: "./src/server/server"`. Also checkout the extensive list of tests https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/tree/master/test

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because looking at all those examples I noticed something that I had done wrong: my "resolve" configuration should have been an object with an "extensions" property. By fixing that, I can now import without extensions. Thanks! Now I feel dumb...

Answer (score 0):

I overcame all the compiling issues and created a project template here, https://github.com/c9s/ts-webpack

You can just clone the project to start without fighting with the config files...